# Consolidate Columns in VBA and Remove Duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

Having difficulty with the code below. I am trying to copy the data from cells B6 to the last row in each worksheet and paste it into a summary sheet. I would then like to remove duplicates. I searched through a few forums and still have no luck.

```
Sub ConsolidateCustomers()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Sheets

    If ws.Name <> "Detailed Aging Summary" And ws.Name <> "Structuring" Then
    Range("B6", .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        destination=Worksheets("Detailed Aging Summary").Range("B3", .Cells(Rows.Count, 
        1).End(xlUp).Row)

    End If

    With Worksheets("Detailed Aging Summary").Range("B3", .Cells(Rows.Count, 
       1).End(xlUp).Row).RemoveDuplicates
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `destination:=Worksheets(...`   and missing `Next ws`.  "Having difficulty" is not a very useful description of the problem - please clarify exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Lots of issues here (missing `Next`, missing `With...End With`, unqualified `Range` calls, etc.) Would suggest that you break this down into pieces and get them working separately before trying to combine code together.